# How to find out which package a user belongs to?

Tags: apt, package-management, users, rpm, dpkg

In Linux distributions, some packages create user accounts.

How can I determine which package created a given user?

I want to know specifically for Fedora and Ubuntu, but answers for other distributions are welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Debian-based systems (including Ubuntu), packages create users using [maintainer scripts](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html), usually `postinst`. Therefore one way could be to grep through these scripts:

```
grep -R --include='*.postinst' -e useradd -e adduser /var/lib/dpkg/info/
```

This assumes, of course, that the `postinst` script hasn't been deleted (either manually or because you uninstalled the package in question).

---

[Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html#s-permissions-owners) seems to favour `postinst`:

> [Y]ou must arrange for your package to create the user or group if necessary using `adduser` in the `preinst` or `postinst` script (again, the latter is to be preferred if it is possible).

The package maintainer can use `preinst` as well, as long as `adduser` is a pre-dependency.

The policy also leads us to the other source of accounts: the `base-passwd` package, as it states in the preceding paragraph:

> If you need a statically allocated id, you must ask for a user or group id from the `base-passwd` maintainer, and must not release the package until you have been allocated one. Once you have been allocated one you must either make the package depend on a version of the `base-passwd` package with the id present in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/group`, or arrange for your package to create the user or group itself with the correct id (using `adduser`) in its `preinst` or `postinst`. (Doing it in the `postinst` is to be preferred if it is possible, otherwise a pre-dependency will be needed on the adduser package.)

The `base-passwd` documentation (`/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.txt.gz` or `/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.html`) says:

```
The Debian base-passwd package contains the master versions of /etc/passwd and
/etc/group. The update-passwd tool keeps the entries in these master files in
sync on all Debian systems. They comprise only "global static" ids: that is,
those which are reserved globally for the benefit of packages which need to
include files owned by those users or groups, or need the ids compiled into
binaries.
```

The users/groups included are (grepped out from `/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.txt.gz`):

#### Users (usually with corresponding groups)

```
root    man     majordom    irc         gdm
daemon  lp      postgres    gnats       saned
bin     mail    www-data    nobody      klog
sys     news    backup      messagebus  syslog
sync    uucp    operator    postfix
games   proxy   list        haldaemon
```

#### Groups (without corresponding users)

```
adm     fax     audio       staff       sshd
tty     voice   src         users       fetchmail
disk    cdrom   shadow      lpadmin     cupsys
kmem    floppy  utmp        sasl        nogroup
dialout tape    video       scanner
dip     sudo    plugdev     ssh
```

The package README (`/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/README`) also lists out some users with UIDs in the 60000-64999 range, and states that these are created by the respective packages.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that such users would only be added in a postinst?

Comment: @FaheemMitha no, nothing prevents then from using preinst, but there's no reason to and Debian policy seems to be to use postinst.

Comment: Ok, in that case a comment about Debian policy would be in order, I think. It is good to quote policy and people don't do so often enough, I think.

Comment: @FaheemMitha perhaps a link to [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47880/70524)?

Comment: It is more reasonable to quote policy in your answer, rather than send readers somewhere else, imo.

Comment: @FaheemMitha updated.

Comment: Looks good. But since I already upvoted, I can't upvote again. :-)

Comment: @FaheemMitha no problem. On the bright side, now I can tell my boss to keep the 60k-65k range out of LDAP. :D

Comment: Boss? You're a student at IITB, right? Or is that out of date?

Comment: @FaheemMitha post-graduate student, so we have to work part time for the department (either as a TA, or in my case, as a sysad).

Comment: Oh, I see. You should join us in chat sometime. You know where it is...

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK there is no native package manager function that creates (or removes) those functional  /system users but that is done in a custom pre- or post-install script sections in RPM packages.

Typically the RPM package will create and claim ownership of the home directory of those users e.g. the `httpd` package creates the user apache and the home directory of the apache user is owned by the httpd package, allowing a round-about way of finding the package:

```
rpm -qf /var/www
```

You can verify if indeed the httpd package could have created the apache user with:

```
rpm -q --scripts httpd
```

Comment: This works if the home directory exists. It doesn't always, e.g. there is an `adm` user on a Fedora host I'm examining whose home directory, `/var/adm`, does not exist.  Still I need to know whether any Fedora package ever created or still uses that user.

Comment: Since the users are created in the script section of RPM files, you can query all of those scripts at once: `rpm -q --all --scripts | grep useradd` which is quite speedy, but doesn't provide really helpful results in regard which specific rpm created the user.

Comment: I just wrote [a Perl script that does this and greps the output](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/bin/user-or-group-in-package-scripts). It appears to be quite effective.

Answer (score 4):

For systems using rpm, this will list all package that use `useradd` on their script

```
rpm -qa | xargs -n1 -I % sh -c 'echo %; rpm -q --scripts % | grep useradd' | grep useradd -B 1
```

With the same command we can search the targeted user by replacing `useradd` on the command with the searched user...

Important note here, many packages/applications create their user when they are ran, so this command won't identify their user.

Answer (score 3):

I use Gentoo, So i would extract the 5th field of /etc/passwd to find the info:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep cron | gawk -F: '{print $5}'
```

added by portage for cronbase

Portage is package management system for Gentoo. So cron account is created by portage for the package cronbase.

Comment: This can be simplified into a single command, `gawk -F: '/code/ {print $5}' /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 2):

Warning: This is a crude way and may not work for all the users created by packages.

Most of the packages that create users will be creating those user's home directories outside /home and most times their home directories will be part of the package. In such cases, you can `rpm -qf` such users home directory and find out the package.

User `ntp`

```
[root@secapp01 ~]# grep ntp /etc/passwd
ntp:x:38:38::/etc/ntp:/sbin/nologin
[root@secapp01 ~]# rpm -qf /etc/ntp
ntpdate-4.2.6p5-1.el6.x86_64
```

User `postfix`

```
[root@secapp01 ~]# grep postfix /etc/passwd
postfix:x:89:89::/var/spool/postfix:/sbin/nologin
[root@secapp01 ~]# rpm -qf /var/spool/postfix
postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_5.x86_64
```

Comment: I thought of this; it works, but only if the home directory exists, which is not always the case on the host I need this for.